# Merge command give Error: cannot allocate vector of size 54.2 Gb

Tags: r, memory, merge

I'm tring to merge in a single database 2 columns of two large database of different lenght, the problem is that the merge command gives me the error

> "*Error: cannot allocate vector of size 54.2 Gb*".

I'm running on windows 10, with 32GB of RAM.
I really can not understand why the final database is so large, the two starting database are one of 350k rows and one of 50k rows. If i merge manually the two colums using SPSS the resulting database if abput 2MB. I need to automate the process so doing it manually is out of question.

```
dbA<-MatrixLarge$varAlpha  

dbB<-MatrixSmall$varBeta


# creating the column id for dataframe 1
dbA = cbind("id"=rownames(dbA),dbA)

# creating column id for dataframe 2
dbB = cbind("id"=rownames(dbB),dbB)

#merging two dataframe
dbFinal<-merge(dbA,dbB,all=T)
```

Comment: I have already increased the memory limit in r up to 100GB but id did not helped

Comment: try to use `data.table` package. from its documentations: "n Fast aggregation of large data (e.g. 100GB in RAM), fast ordered joins, fast add/modify/delete of columns....". Here the [merge function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.8/topics/merge)  form `data.table` and here the package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)

Comment: Try to specify `merge(dbA, dbB, by = "id", all = TRUE)`

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the class of you database, as well as the shape of your variables. Would it be possible to share some sample data e.g. the first 50 rows of your databases? I've added a simple reproducible example below, which works without a problem:

Comment: `# sample data
dbA <- data.frame(1:350000)
dbB <- data.frame( sample(letters[1:26],50000,replace=TRUE))

# creating the column id for dataframe A and B
dbA = cbind("id"=sample(1:50000,replace=TRUE),dbA)
dbB = cbind("id"=sample(1:50000),dbB)

#merging two dataframe
system.time(dbFinal<-merge(dbA,dbB,all=T))`
   user  system elapsed 
  0.790   0.035   0.830 

`system.time(dbFinal<-merge(dbA,dbB,all=T,by="id"))`
   user  system elapsed 
  0.902   0.032   0.941

Comment: @EnricoImbimbo, glad to hear. If it answered your question you can mark my question as "Accepted", which will let others know that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably merging across several columns, try using `merge(dbA, dbB, by = "id", all = TRUE)` to only merge by `id`, otherwise the result will be too large, as indicated by the memory error.